# Lists without bullets points in Markdown

Tags: markdown

I want to create a list in Markdown, but without bullet points. Is that possible?

The only recommended ways I found so far are using HTML, which I want to avoid.

Comment: usually, markdown is used to export to HTML (or other formats)... what do you mean with "The only recommended ways I found so far are using HTML, which I want to avoid"? btw, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Yeah, that's the point. Export to HTML, not write in HTML. Often you can mix Markdown and HTML, but my question is, if there is a way to write it in Markdown.

Comment: use CSS to remove the bullets of the generated HTML list?

Comment: I appreciate your idea, but I am looking for a solution for doing this with Markdown only. I know I could modify the HTML or CSS afterwards, but that's not what I'm looking for. If there is no way to do that, that would be an answer, too ;)

Comment: So you want to change the way that the browser displays the HTML rendered by Markdown? That would require CSS. Or if you want different HTML to be output (which doesn't use `<li>`), then that would need to use raw HTML in your Markdown (although, it is not clear to me what that HTML would be without some CSS to make it look like a list). There are no other options.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, with *pure* markdown this is not possible.

Think of Markdown as a simpler syntax for HTML. To change the styling you'll need to add a CSS to the generated HTML.

Answer (score 26):

This might sound obvious but... you could understand a list as "lines separated by line breaks" (when you think about the output, not the markup).

```
First item  (<-- two spaces)  
Second item
```

This will render to:

First item
Second item

This looks like a list with no bullet points :)
[A more beautiful example.](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#linebreaks)

Comment: This works, but I have my editor configured to strip trailing whitespace on save and don't want to toggle that off and on all the time.

Comment: @jdgregson Many editors have a solution for your issue :) Disable trimming trailing whitspaces for markdown. [Quick fix for VSCode](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/1679)

Answer (score 6):

Like @mb21 specified, here is the CSS if someone needs:

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-left: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't really specific to Github, but, if that were the case, you could then leverage the native CSS styling there:

```html
<div id="user-content-toc">
  <ul>
    ...
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: How did you go about discovering this in particular? I'm hunting around, and on the profile page the repositories list on the left uses class `list-styles-none` but it doesn't work in my README.

Comment: I don't remember exactly what triggered the realization, but I remember it involved a lot of trying different things and investigating how the behavior of the page changed with the browser inspector.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply put the items in new lines with every line ends with

Example:

```
item 1 <br/>
item 2 <br/>
item 3 <br/>
item 4 <br/>
```