# Can you use an Image bullet for LI in mark-down?

Tags: markdown, r-markdown

I would like to know if it is possible to use an image for a list item instead of a normal bullet point in mark-down. Basically I want to use a special small icon for each bullet in the list.

Comment: Hope this will help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32474227/lists-without-bullets-points-in-markdown?rq=1

Comment: Not unless you want to use raw HTML (and you're using it somewhere that allows some freedom in your styling).