# How do I indent items in the sections part of my markdown file?

Tags: jekyll

My sections file is currently:

```
sections:
  - Link 1
  - Link 2
  - Link 3
```

That produces a simple navigation:

Link 1

Link 2

Link 3

I would like to add sublinks that are indented like so:

- Link 1

  - Sublink

(only without the bullets)

I tried indenting the sections:

```
 - Link 1
   - Sublink
```

But that only puts the sublink on the same line as the link above it.

Link 1 Sublink

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there is no way to do that in markdown. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32474227/lists-without-bullets-points-in-markdown#32485056) out.

But you can do it in HTML&CSS. With this code I have achieved what you specify:

```html
- link
  <ul style="list-style-type:none">
  <li> sublink1  </li>
  <li> sublink2  </li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you need a lot more information here. That YAML alone does not produce any navigation. Adding sub links here would depend on how your Liquid templates are using this YAML.

If you are asking for the syntax of a nested list, it is:

```
sections:
  - Link 1:
    - Sublink 1
    - Sublink 2
```

Note the colon after Link 1.

If you want to remove the bullet points before each item, you would use CSS (depend on how you are rendering your HTML), e.g.

```
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```