# Is there a way to add color to a bulleted list?

Tags: r-markdown, bulletedlist

I would like to add color to a bulleted list within a text portion of an RMarkdown script intended for HTML. I've tried many different things that all seem to work for a single line of text, but not for multiple lines. Here is an example. The first line "I am red text" ends up rendering in red, but the bulleted list do not:

```
<span style="color: red;"> I am red text </span>

<span style="color: red;">

  * bullet1
  * bullet2
  * bullet3
  
</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

Following a new information in the comments by the OP, here is a solution for multi colored bullet lists:

````
---
title: "Red bullets"
author: bttomio
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

<font color='red'>

  * bullet1
  * bullet2
  * bullet3

</font>

  * bullet1
  * bullet2
  * bullet3
````

-output

[image]

---

You can change the CSS to change the color. I just modified the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54919953/13249862), adding `color: red;`.

Here is a simple ```.Rmd

````
---
title: "Red bullets"
author: bttomio
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

```{css, echo = F}
ul {
    color: red;
}
```

  * bullet1
  * bullet2
  * bullet3
````

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. This does turn the list red for me. It also turns all bulleted lists in the document red. Is there a way to single out one bulleted list and leave the rest black? Also, being new to this, I think I would benefit from a primer on how to use CSS. Do you have any recommendations on a resource to learn the basics?

Comment: Could you please be more precise in your question? You're adding a new information here (multi colored bullet lists). I found a solution using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56593416/13249862). I am not so sure about a primer on how to use CSS. You will find lots on information on SO and over the web.

Comment: Perfect. That works well and looks like a very simple solution. Thanks!

Comment: can we change the bullet color only?

Comment: @AdeDyas, yes. For example: <font color='red'> *</font> bullet1